# List of "Linked" questions across network sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, linked-questions

The list of "Linked" questions can be very helpful to quickly find questions that are related to the current question, for the case that the current Q/A is not *exactly* what one was looking for.

This does not only refer to questions and answers that are related in the sense of the "Related" category (which seems to be based on title and tags), but also in the sense of a human-detected relationship, which clearly goes beyond what can be detected automatically.

<sub>(An aside: The most interesting part of the "Linked" list are the "Who links here?"-Links. The other ones could also be found manually)</sub>

However, these links to not seem to cover cross-site linkings. I think that it could be very interesting to include links between the various programming-related sites. For example, it could be nice to see whether there are links from a particular question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ to a question/answer on http://stackoverflow.com , or vice versa.

<sub>This is taged as [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), but it is rather a suggestion, pointing out that it might be a "nice to have" feature</sub>

Comment: cross-site related, maybe even duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147096/span-stack-exchange-sites-for-tags-searches-and-related-questions

Comment: @rene Certainly related, but this question seems to propose a *very* invasive, conceptual merge e.g. of tags. Although I'm not familiar with the underlying technologies, I could imagine that extracting some links could be possible *without* introducing unwanted dependencies or overlaps among the sites. It's just an idea, and I wanted to suggest it here...

Comment: Yes! I second! I recently used a chain of related knowledge across SO, serverfault and askubuntu to solve a python problem. I just got lucky with google but these answers could have been linked!